# Javascript Browser Snippet open multiple websites

Tags: javascript, code-snippets

I want to write a little helper with a Javascript Browser Snippet that opens multiple urls in my local environment. In Chrome, open DevTools => Sources => Snippets and create a new Snippet. Here I tried the following:

```
const skins = ["skin1", "skin2", "skin3"]
const openAllSkins = () => {
skins.map(skin => window.open(`http://${skin}.loc.mylocalenv.com:7000`, `_blank`)
}
openAllSkins()
```

When I run the snippet (right click the snippet => Run), it only opens the first skin. Why doesn't it work for all the other skins? When debugging, I can proof that the mapping runs through all skins, but somehow only the first one will be opened.

Any hints much appreciated.

[image: Screenshot of how to write and run this snippet in Chrome DevTools]

Comment: Assuming that there is no syntax error, did your browser blocks the rest of the popups?

Comment: ! Indeed! Thank you! I allowed pop-ups for redirects from chrome developer tools and violá, everything opens as expected! Again, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

**Allow pop-ups** from your website for all the windows to open. This will work. Thanks.

[image]